# How could I use POV-Ray with an .stl file for merge with object?

Tags: merge, 3d, povray, stl-format

I have this povray code:

```
#include "colors.inc"
camera{
  location <4, 4, -10>
  look_at 0
  angle 36
}

light_source{ <500, 500, -1000> White }

plane{ y, -1.5
  pigment{ checker Green White }
}

union{
  box{ -1, 1 pigment{ Blue } }
  sphere{ 0, 1.375 pigment{ Red } }
  sphere{<0,1,0>,1.35  pigment{ Blue } }
  cone{<0,0,0>,0.45,<0,1.2,0>,0 pigment{ Blue } }
}
```

povray +Imerge.pov

I would like to add an .stl file to `union`. How could I do that?

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

POV-Ray does not support STL files per se, you'll have to use a converter to achieve the desired outcome.

Check out stl2pov (https://github.com/timschmidt/stl2pov), or any other tools from the official list at http://www.povray.org/resources/links/3D_Programs/Conversion_Utilities/.